# Prove that $m=(x+y^2, y+x^2+2xy^2+y^4)$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

Tags: ring-theory

> Prove that $m=(x+y^2, y+x^2+2xy^2+y^4)$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$.

I can show that the ideal $(x,y)$ of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ contains $m$ and $(x,y)$ is a maximal ideal. Therefore to show that $m$ is itself a maximal ideal I only need to show that $m=(x,y)$. I tried to prove it by looking for two polynomials $f,g$ such that $x=f(x,y)(x+y^2)+g(x,y)(y+x^2+2xy^2+y^4)$ but wasn't able to find them. And I'm not sure whether this is the best way of proving this. I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Tbrendle said in the comments, you can show that $\mathbb C[x,y]/m$ is a field. This is equivalent to $m$ being a maximal ideal of $\mathbb C[x,y]$.

So consider the quotient $R:= \mathbb C[x,y]/m$. We want to compute some residue classes. Note that in this ring we have $x=-y^2$. This implies that
$$0= y+y^4-2y^4+y^4=y.$$ So by these identifications, we have $$ R \simeq \mathbb C[y]/(y) \simeq \mathbb C.$$ This is a field, and we're done.

Comment: +1. No need to compute ugly linear combinations in the given ring when computing directly in the quotient ring.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, $x=\color{red}{f(x,y)}(x+y^2)+\color{green}{g(x,y)}(y+x^2+2xy^2+y^4)$ with, for example, $\color{red}{f(x,y)}=1-(x+y^2)^3$ and $\color{green}{g(x,y)}=(x+y^2)^2-y$.

This can be found by noting that $a=x+y^2$ and $b=y+x^2+2xy^2+y^4$ are such that $b=y+a^2$ hence $x=a-y^2=a-(b-a^2)^2$. Thus, $x=\color{red}{(1-a^3)}a+\color{green}{(2a^2-b)}b$.

Answer (score 2):

In general, $(x-q(y),p(x,y))$ equals $(x-q(y),p(q(y),y))$, because $p(x,y) \equiv p(q(y),y)$ modulo $x-q(y)$. Here, $(x+y^2,y+x^2+2xy^2 + y^4)=(x+y^2,y+y^4-2 y^4+y^4)=(x+y^2,y)=(x,y)$.